# Can you argue against a moral absolute by saying yes it's rational, but not practically so?

Tags: metaethics

Can you argue against a moral absolute by saying yes it's rational, because it's true, but not practically so?

So can you, in principle, coherently claim that it is true that not lying is good, and so the obligation not to lie is rational, but sometimes it is rational to lie?

I hope so, though I'm probably wrong.

Perhaps [practical moral skepticism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/skepticism-moral/supplement.html) can account for it being moral to lie to save the fugitive, but in this instance there's no rational need to be moral. Wouldn't that mean lying is irrational but not practically so?

As to why believe (at all) in practical moral skepticism, couldn't something like 'relevance' temper the irrationality of moral actions? A watertight mathematical proof sounds supremely rational, but sometimes irrelevant, and so sometimes it is irrational to work on it. Why not, analogously, performing moral actions?

Comment: I would say no because the scenario here is the moral absolute is still correct and this is not under dispute. Your focus on practical indicates that you might allegedly rationalize to do something you KNOW is wrong to prevent a negative result from occurring to you. I.e., you commit adultry and the video leaked but you try to lie and say it's not you to prevent divorce. The objective truth remains intact. You are just trying to be slick and get away with stuff. You can lie to save someone from being murdered. This again is practical but only to prevent undesirable results. Just come clean.

Comment: no, i'm talking about lying to stop a murder. this seems to be a conclusion from kant, just one he may have missed? we can't just ignore it and hope it goes away... @Logikal

Comment: You ate likely confusing truth value with the result. The two are independent of each other.  The same way you can't combine different variables in mathematics.  Because x is practical some of the time does not make x morally correct. As a matter of fact it proves unreliable. Absolute means the value cannot change over time with given circumstances. This is summarized with the term objective.  Objective means x is always right or wrong in the exact circumstances given without exception. One false case proves the the method unreliable and untrustworthy. A person makes an error doing so.

Comment: i'm confused, i never mentioned truth value, or result @Logikal

Comment: The purpose of you mentioning the practical has nothing to do with the result?? Why bring it up then? Morals have truth values by definition so you dont have to literally mention it. Practical implies results and moral implies objective truth value.

Comment: yeah it has something to do with the result. think we're talking past each other though @Logikal it could just be your tone that's confusing me so much, not sure

Comment: I can't make sense of what is asked here but maybe it's just me... The style of this question seems suspiciously familiar.

Comment: there's no need to actually put me down @Eliran several users seem to have understood the question, so maybe it is just you?

Comment: @Eliran maybe we should move the discussion to chat to work out, or try to, what you're not understanding, if it's a general style issue...

Comment: i'm guessing the question is just too basic to understand for people who are familiar with philosophy... hm @Eliran

Comment: @another_name I'm definitely open to the possibility that it's just me. I can say what I find confusing, if it helps. For example, I'm not sure what you mean by 'and so the obligation not to lie is rational, but sometimes it is rational to lie?', because it seems like a contradiction. You probably mean morally rational in the first use of 'rational' and some other kind of rationality (practical?) in the second. In any case I'm not sure what the relation to moral absolutes is supposed to be exactly. Again, maybe it's just me.

Comment: yeah that's the point of most of my questions, trying to work out what's up with a supposed paradox / contradiction. i appreciate the reply @Eliran !

Comment: "Several users seem to have understood the question"? Are you sure? Or perhaps, they just took the opportunity to indulge in the comment generation that you seem to love. It would be better if you changed your posting style instead of the user name. "Technically wrong but morally right" is a widely used idiom. What it means is that "moral absolute" is a commendable sentiment, but false nonetheless, as an absolute. But it takes more work to turn this into an actual question.

Comment: i think you're just looking for a clear cut answer, rather than to understand the question @Conifold even clear questions can be answered or framed in more than one way. imho. concepts overlap, so can generate different ways of answering even without ambiguity. i didn't ask anyone to comment

Comment: what i mean is that just because you're not sure if of how an idiom you know relates to the question that does not mean that the question is not clear @Conifold i guess that's the issue here

Comment: We are looking for clear cut questions, however the answers are framed. "Generating different ways" of what the question is means exactly that it is unclear, and not a question for SE. For the sort of multifaceted discussion you enjoy the proper venue is [Philosophy Forum](https://thephilosophyforum.com/). Here, we are looking not for more comments with justifications, but for change in behavior.

Comment: hm not sure i agree that makes it unclear @Conifold but whatever

Comment: no i mean, the question IS imho unequivocal, the fact you don't know how to answer it doesn't change that @Conifold

Answer (score 1):

> So can you, in principle, coherently claim that lying is always irrational, but sometimes it is rational to lie?

No, not really. If lying is *always* wrong, then it is *always* wrong. However, it may be helpful to keep in mind here the distinction between [moral absolutism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_absolutism) and [moral universalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_universalism). Lying might be wrong in a universal way, without being absolute. In other words, if there are certain circumstances that always make lying excusable or good, these circumstances might be universal and/or [deontological](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontological_ethics) (that is according to inherent ethical rules and not results or outcomes).

Comment: yeah i'm aware of the difference! i'm asking about lying to save the fugitive, repugnant conclusions from the CI